# Refresh tokens without an iframe

Tags: identityserver3

I have an app working using the oidc-client-js. The silent refresh works great. Problem is that the refresh is using an iframe and our IT department have decided iframes are bad and have disabled them on their new network they are rolling out!

Is there a way to refresh the token without an iframe or doing a whole redirect back to the id server to get a new token.

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible for you to use Resource Owner flow?

Comment: No. This is all hosted behind an SSO solution, defeats the object by sending a username and password. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can request new tokens by redirecting the main browser window, or do it in a popup window. The oidc-client library supports all three.

Comment: So our code falls back to redirecting if it cannot get the refresh token via the iframe, but this disrupts the users flow and unless we code something restarts the app. I haven't tried the popup window recently, when we tried it a while back we found the popup was blocked by the browser.

I was hoping there would be a wonderful non iframe solution which refreshed the token without the user being aware...

Comment: BTW thanks for replying. We shall relook at the popup for the new network and see if this works. If there is any other suggestion tho that would be cool.